# Read multi-line output into other variable in shell

Tags: shell, parsing

I have an output from a process that looks like this:

```json
{
    "v1":  "x0482030ssj09645j34"
}
```

I need to parse this output in order to extract x0482030ssj09645j34.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a handy JSON parser. In this case, you can do

```sh
your_process | jq -r '.v1'
```

to output just that value

Comment: Thanks! But this will not work for me, as I cannot assume that I have jq installed...